# How to create a one to many relationship in two different custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

i have two different custom post types - authors and travel reports - i want to link the author to his / hers travel reports. how can i achieve this?

thanks.

wolfram

Comment: connect them using post meta is suitable for you? Do you have any code you started with?

Comment: And what posts do you have in authors post type. If you dont store them as users, maybe is better to keep them in custom taxonomy. Then you will be able to connect travel posts with checkbox, like you connect simple post with category.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i use now two plugins to solve it. advanced custom fields and custom post type ui

Comment: Usually I use own metaboxes and fields if I don't need a lot of them. If you want to connect 2 post types without a questions from my side, it's actually easy to do wtih ACF to. In wordpress by default already exist `wp_dropdown_posts`, ACF has similar field type - `post object`, where you can select a post type and recieve posts from choosen post type in dropdown view. I guess this field saves `post_id` value, so later you a able to show posts by these ids. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/ So, what help do you need here?

Comment: post meta will require a `meta_query` which will be very expensive and does not scale. Taxonomies can group travel reports under a term representing the author, but it isn't necessary to use either meta or terms, Antti's answer references the ideal data storage and best case scenario for performance

Answer (score 1):

`WP_Post` has a property `post_parent` by default. Usually this is used for parent-child relationship on hierarchical post types, such as pages, but nothing actually prevents you from linking two different post type posts together with it.

You'll just need a metabox on your travel report CPT, which allows you to select an author CPT post (id) as the parent. This select should have `post_parent` as its name so that the value gets saved to the right property.